# A nonsense story

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, story

> A sandy lover of this here website,
>   only did the Foxtrot once, when they weren't on.
>   Their favourite colour was that of a magical swamp,
>   where they found a crystal that controlled time.
>   They watched TV and saw Judy, Rinder, and Dredd.
>   And when they accessed a Malaysian website,
>   they kept a promise, in sickness, and in health.

Each line of this seemingly nonsense story is a clue to a word.
These words form a sentence.
Can you tell me what this sentence is, and what's special about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A sandy lover of this here website,

> **Sphinx**, found in the desert and known for puzzles.

only did the Foxtrot once, when they weren't on.

> **Of**, the opposite of "on" with only one F.

Their favourite colour was that of a magical swamp,

> **Black**, the colour of swamp cards in Magic: The Gathering. (from OP)

where they found a crystal that controlled time.

> **Quartz**, crystal that's found in watches.

They watched TV and saw Judy, Rinder, and Dredd.

> **Judge** (Judge Judy, Judge Rinder, Judge Dredd)

And when they accessed a Malaysian website,

> **My** (Internet domain for Malaysia)

they kept a promise, in sickness, and in health.

> **Vow**, a promise made in a wedding.

All together

> **Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.**

Which is an example of

> a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) (sentence which uses every letter at least once).

Comment: Hot damn, that was quick. Could you perhaps add a little bit more explanation to each of your answers so other people can follow along?

Comment: Awesome, thank you, one more thing (rot13) gur pbybhe bs n zntvpny fjnzc ersref gb zntvp gur tngurevat jurer gur fjnzc ynaq pneq tvirf oynpx znan

Comment: @AHKieran Ahh, I see. I was wondering about that. I'll edit it in :)

Comment: I assume you were aware of the whole, and after solving a couple of the clues, managed to fill the rest in and work backwards?

Comment: @AHKieran Hadn't heard it before, just solved lines 4&5 and happened to get lucky with Google :)

Comment: :0 cheater!!!!!